# Teste Unitário - Como verificar um erro esperado?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testes-de-unidade, mocha

Em um teste unitário para um módulo utilizando `Mocha` e `Chai` preciso verificar se um erro é retornado caso o formato do parâmetro seja inválido.

A função do módulo em questão retorna uma `Promise`.

O exemplo abaixo é fictício porém tem o resultado do problema real.

```
const FORMATO_PLACA = /^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$/gim;
const ESPECIAIS     = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/gi;

async function validar(placa) {
  placa = placa.replace(ESPECIAIS, '');

  if (!FORMATO_PLACA.test(placa)) {
    throw new Error('Formato de placa inválido! Utilize o formato "AAA999" ou "AAA-9999".');
  }

  return placa;
}

module.exports = {validar};
```

E o código do teste é algo como:

```
const modulo = require('../modulo');
const chai   = require('chai');
const path   = require('path');

const expect  = chai.expect;

describe('validar', function() {
  it('Falhar ao informar um formato inválido', async function() {
    return expect(await modulo.validar('AAAAAAA')).to.throw('Formato de placa inválido! Utilize o formato "AAA999" ou "AAA-9999"');
  });
});
```

Porém com o teste acima o teste falha quando na realidade o erro esperado é apresentado. Como posso testar corretamente o resultado esperado para o erro de uma função assíncrona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseada em uma issue no Chai (https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/415) segue a solução:

```
const modulo = require('../modulo');
const chai   = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

const expect  = chai.expect;

describe('validar', function() {
  it.only('Falhar ao informar um formato inválido', function() {
    return expect(modulo.validar('AAAAAAA')).to.be.rejectedWith(Error);
  });

});
```